# How to get average of a list in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, average

Here is my dataframe. I am looking to calculate the average of the current, voltage, and power of each switch individually.

```
                  switch12            switch11            switch10
Current  [0.1, 0.12, 0.15]  [0.15, 0.11, 0.13]  [0.18, 0.17, 0.15]
Voltage         [120, 118]          [120, 116]          [120, 117]
Power             [12, 25]            [18, 19]        [21.6, 22.4]
```

looking to have the output be something like this:

```
                  switch12            switch11            switch10
Current              0.123               0.130               0.167
Voltage                119                 118               118.5
Power                 18.5                18.5                22.0
```

if there is another method which does not utilize pandas to help with this I am open to hearing about that too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method:

```py
out = df.explode([*df.columns]).groupby(level=0).mean()
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
           switch12  switch11    switch10
Current    0.123333      0.13    0.166667
Power     18.500000     18.50   22.000000
Voltage  119.000000    118.00  118.500000
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `applymap`

```py
df = df.applymap(np.mean)

# or

df = df.applymap(lambda l: sum(l) / len(l))
```

```
print(df)

     switch12  switch11    switch13
0    0.123333      0.13    0.166667
1  119.000000    118.00  118.500000
2   18.500000     18.50   22.000000
```